# How to move Mint transaction data to GnuCash

Tags: accounting, gnucash

Online financial aggregators are great for getting transactions from all of your accounts into one place, but the accounting tools they provide are pretty minimal. I'm a Mint user, and I like the idea of letting Mint manage the connection to my bank, but I need to get the data into a real accounting package: GnuCash.

Mint provides the data in CSV format. So far I have been able to convert that data into QIF. The file format for QIF was simple enough that I was able to write my own conversion tool.

However, with QIF I can only import data from one account at a time. Ideally I would like to be able to download transactions from all of my accounts at once. Here's a sample of Mint data with a few accounts in it:

```
Date,Description,Original Description,Amount,Transaction Type,Category,Account Name,Labels,Notes
3/29/2014,BART,BART-POWELL QPS 5104646979 CA 94102 US C_OTHERTRAVEL,20,debit,Public Transportation,CapitolOne Visa,,
3/28/2014,Student Loan Payment,MY STUDENT LOAN LENDER,40,debit,Student Loan,Checking,,
3/28/2014,Check 995525,Check Paid #995525,64,debit,Check,Checking,,
3/28/2014,Mortgage,MY MORTGAGE COMPANY,1.95,debit,Credit Card Payment,OtherChecking,,
3/28/2014,Paycheck,MY EMPLOYER,1,000,000.00,credit,Paycheck,Checking,,
```

It would be nice if I could take this file and process it once and output a file that GnuCash could then import into the correct accounts. I was working with an [OFX converter](https://code.google.com/p/hle-ofx-quotes/wiki/Csv2OfxCmd), but I'm not clear that OFX can combine data from multiple accounts into a single file due to the requirement to have a ledger balance line.

Is this a reasonable way to try to move data from Mint to GnuCash?

Answer (score 3):

I've written up a Python suite called [csv2cash](https://github.com/u2berggeist/csv2cash) that will take the csv that comes out of Mint and put it into GNUCash. It's setup so that it can be easily rerun several times without much user input.

The other big thing that this does that I haven't seen implemented is it will attempt to resolve accounts transfers between your bank accounts. For example, if your bank does automatic transfers from your savings to your checking account, a simple CSV import won't pick up on this and will create two separate transactions. csv2cash will actually look at transfers with the same value, figure out if there are any matching transfers that also go to the users bank accounts, and then combines them together into a single GNUCash transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I am also looking to do exactly what you describe. 
I just came across [mintcash](https://github.com/hiromu2000/mintcash) and it looks like it has the functionality.
 Granted this solution requires some python knowledge, no code generation should be required. 
It uses two other libraries:[mintapi](https://github.com/mrooney/mintapi) and [piecash](https://github.com/sdementen/piecash)
I just attempted to do this but it seems that mintapi currently has a login issue that is literally two days old at this writing due to mint changing some authentication related calls. Hopefully someone will patch it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch accounts and transactions using intuit(Mint) API. This requires to apply for dev. account.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=FinancialData#getAccountTransactions

Comment: This is a good answer if you have some programming know-how, and don't want to write the conversion more than once :)

Answer (score 0):

GnuCash has a CSV import option!

Comment: I should have mentioned in my original post: the CSV import process in GnuCash was way too combersome. Every time you import you have to redo the column and data-type matching for each field.

Comment: The current CSV importer is a great improvement and allows customizing the columns as well as saving the configuration setups.